# Unable to resize the chrome window size when tests running on selenium Grid

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am facing one issue when tried to maximize the remote chrome browser to a specific size when tests are written in C# running on Selenium Grid. 
I tried below options

- options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920, 1080");
- Driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);

But, the browser does not maximize.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
                _webDriver = new ChromeDriver("c:\path"), options);
                _wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                _webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately, it didn't work. :(

Comment: make sure you update _webdriver to whatever you are using for your driver. What happens when  you debug it?